# In Django/Python I relate an object (A) to two instances of another object (B) so that if I call B.A_set.all(), it works for either instance of B

Tags: python, django

EDIT: The solution provided works!

I have written a modified ELO rating system for FIFA. I want to show an ELO leaderboard with players (I can produce this), show a game history, and also have the option to select a player and see their personal game history. My intended version of the classes is presented below. I can produce the leaderboard and game history if I set the player1 and player2 attribute of Game to a string and define the name manually but I want the game and players to be related.

When I try to migrate this solution presented to mySQL this is the error message

```
ERRORS:
blog.Game.player1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Game.player1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Game.player2'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Game.player1' or 'Game.player2'.
blog.Game.player2: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Game.player2' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Game.player1'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Game.player2' or 'Game.player1'.
```

## Models.py folder within django

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    elo = models.IntegerField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + " = " + str(self.elo) + " - Joined " +
                    str(date_add)
```

```
class Game(models.Model):
    date_played = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    player1 = models.ForeignKey(Player,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    p1goal = models.IntegerField()
    player2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    p2goal = models.ForeignKey(Player,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date_played) + " - " + str(self.player1.name) + " " + str(self.p1goal) + " to " + \
               str(self.p2goal) + str(self.player2.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `Player` model twice., which causes duplicates in `reverse relations`., if u don't want reverse relations at all., use `related_name = +`.

```
player1 = models.ForeignKey(Player,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")

or

p2goal = models.ForeignKey(Player,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
```

for more information [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#inheritance-and-reverse-relations)

Comment: Thank you for the documentation I will update if works! Migration is currently not migrating my classes so I gotta work that bug out first

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the "name" attribute of your player model isn't set as the primary key of the model. Perhaps you need to access each instance of player with its primary key. Right now, that primary key will be a number that corresponds to each player in the order that they were added.

Comment: That is a good tip I will consider adding it in. I designed the ELO separately so I am currently working building the webpage (It also acts as a personal blog with other information) but once I learn how the forms work for adding players I will consider making the primary key the name but I want people to be able to type their name in and I am not sure how it works with strings just yet.